# Change static variables

Tags: java, variables, static

I would like know whether it's possible to change the code below that the second output prints the changed variables that I get "2.2noo100onn" instead of "1.1foo200oof"?

Is it possible to return multiple types from different types or is there a way I can crate an mixed variable type array?

The code I'm working on is a lot bigger, but this example works the same way.

```
public class test 
{
    static String s1 = "foo";
    static String s2 = "oof";
    static double d1 = 1.1;
    static int i1 = 200;

       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
            // Ausgabe Hello World!
            System.out.println(d1+s1+i1+s2);

            bla();
            System.out.println(d1+s1+i1+s2);
       }

    public static void bla() {
         String s1 = "noo";
         String s2 = "onn";
         double d1 = 2.2;
         int i1 = 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

In method bla() you are re-declaring the variables, such that the new variables have local scope.  They are actually different variables from the ones you declared and initialized at the beginning of your class.  Instead, manipulate the class-scope variables in this way:

```
public static void bla() {
     s1 = "noo";
     s2 = "onn";
     d1 = 2.2;
     i1 = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want your `bla` method to change the static variables, don't hide them. When you re-declare those variables in that method, you are creating new local variables, that only exist within the scope of the method.

Change your code to:

```
public static void bla() 
{
     s1 = "noo";
     s2 = "onn";
     d1 = 2.2;
     i1 = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void bla() {
     String s1 = "noo"; //s1 is a local variable that's never used
     String s2 = "onn";
     double d1 = 2.2;
     int i1 = 100;
     //s1, s2, d1 and i1 will be destroyed and garbage collected here
}
```

You're *declaring* a new String object and hiding the *class members*. `s1` here is not the same String that's a class member.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .....

```
public class test 
{
    static String s1 = "foo";
    static String s2 = "oof";
    static double d1 = 1.1;
    static int i1 = 200;

       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
             // Ausgabe Hello World!
             System.out.println(d1+s1+i1+s2);

            bla();
             System.out.println(d1+s1+i1+s2);
       }

       public static void bla() 
       {
           s1 = "noo";
           s2 = "onn";
           d1 = 2.2;
           i1 = 100;
       }
}
```